# Create stand-alone system services in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, service, rubygems, sinatra

I want to build application which servers as a stand-alone system service, always run on the backend and servers a front-end with a web interface.

Like we do in Linux `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` , Same as I want to server my application `/etc/init.d/myapp start`.

My major target is to deliver on Linux specially Ubuntu, whole app would be in plain Ruby and front-end would be in Sinatra.

I want to make it install with simple, `gem install my_app` and command line features get available to start the service. The application would be doing heavily processing and database insertion. And I want that its configurations must be set as in pure linux fashion, like `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Can any one guide me in it? Also if possible, i want to secure the code, is there any possibilities for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [the Daemon-Kit gem](https://github.com/kennethkalmer/daemon-kit) for the same requirements. Works very well in production. The only thing it does not include is the configuration with a .conf file, but it's easy to do it yourself with Ruby code. You can deploy with Capistrano, no need to install.

Comment: Not provided out the box by Daemon-kit. But any Ruby-level code protection should work (I don't know anything in this domain)